# Microsoft SDN service templates deployment and editing

Tags: scvmm, microsoft

I’m playing around SCVMM 2016 SDN Express to see if I’d be able to deploy VMM SDN within my lab using PowerShell scripts. I don't have much practice in things like these, so please bear with me

This article I’ve found(https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/how-to-deploy-software-defined-networking-with-vmm-sdn-express-for-scvmm-2016) seems to be providing a pretty much detailed guideline, however I’m still wondering how to properly import and edit the SDN service templates.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this Microsoft [doc for more info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/sdn-controller?view=sc-vmm-1801).
You’re looking for the ‘Set up the service template’ section.
In a nutshell, you copy a template from VMM >Templates > NC to your VMM server, import it, and update the parameters for your environment. To customize it, you select it and open it in designer mode.